# Default website returns 503 on TFS/Build box

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5

Okay, here goes: Our developers are running VS 2012 on Win 7 boxes. I am running TFS 11 on my Win Server 2008 R2 box with IIS 7.5. It runs fine. My gating unit tests fail however. While I am  not completely certain what the issue is, I seem to be unable to get the default Web Site or our application that I have installed under it to run. The default web site won't even return a test.htm file choosing instead to return a 503. To date I have tried...

- Setting up WCF with access to the test cert installed on the box
- Changing the app pool and giving it access to the dir in question
- Burning a small offering to the gods of oblique IIS issues
- Various other things I can't recall at the moment

I would take Sean Walsh's advice at the end of this post: http://forums.iis.net/t/1183179.aspx/2/10 but I need SQL reporting services for my TFS to work properly.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean Walsh had it nailed. This turned out to be due to the fact that SQL server reporting services were using the port at the behest of TFS. I was able to step around this problem by setting up a dedicated build box on a VM.